# how to set button gravity right in toolbar?

Tags: android

I have button include in toolbar but I don't set gravity right.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <include
    layout="@layout/btn_share"
    android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

manifest.xml

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
```

Layout file(MainActivity.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#B0BEC5"
tools:context="com.example.raj.jazzflurry.MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/faqfoods_bar"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#F4B702"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <include
                layout="@layout/btn_share"
                android:id="@+id/btn_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<!--Your View what you want-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

include Layout File btn_share

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add one answer . It will be better if you edit first answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all,

It is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include layout="@layout/btn_share"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```